# Offline image caching Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mobile, firebase-storage

Is there a way to cache images from Firebase storage for viewing when the user is offline?

Here is my scenario, I have a list of user records saved to Firestore. Using Firebase offline capabilities, I can view any user's information when the device goes offline, but the user's image doesn't get loaded.

I am using cache_network_image plugin already, but it only caches images of users I have previously viewed while online. Is there a way I can automatically cache all user's images?

Comment: Well... you could preload all images, but are you sure that is the best use of your user's bandwidth? It depends on the exact use-case of course, but if the user is only likely to see a small fraction of all the images - it might be better to only cache a subset of the images and use a fallback for the rest.

Comment: The user is aware, and the images can be viewed randomly when the application is offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood [cached_network_image[https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) uses [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

You should be able to leverage this by fetching all of the image URLs and using the `getImageFile` method of [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

Sample Code

```dart
List<String> allImageUrls = await yourFirebaseApi.getAllImageUrls();

// NOTE: This might cause performance issues so it's best to do this in a queue
//       so each image will be fetched one by one, not at the same time
allImageUrls.forEach(
  (url) => await DefaultCacheManager().getImageFile(url),
);
```

Comment: Thank you Zonily, I was able to get the desired result.